# RMAN Catalog requirement with DataGuard

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman

If you have an 11g or 19c Oracle Standby DB setup using dataguard must you use an RMAN catalog when backing it up? I ask, because it was a requirement in much older versions of Oracle (e.g. 9i) but I can't find confirmation in the documentation of later releases. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you cite your source for such a requirement in 9i?  I cannot find such.  Keeping in mind that the primary repository of backup information is _always_ the database control file, I cannot see an rman catalog being a requirement.

Comment: It may well have been a recommendation. I read it in a blog not official documentation. But, regardless, I guess the answer to my question is no. So thanks for that,